# How best to queue file uploads to S3 in a multi server environment?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, redis

In short, my API will accept file uploads. I (ultimately) store them in S3, but to save uploading them to S3 on the same request, I queue the upload process and do it in the background.

I was originally storing the file on the server, and in my job, I was queueing the file path, and then grabbing the contents with that file path on the server, and then sending to S3.

I develop/stage on a single server. My production environment will sit behind a load balancer, with 2-3 servers. I realised that my jobs will fail 2/3 of the time as the file that I am linking to in my job may be on a different server and not on the server running the job.

I realised I could just `base64_encode` the file contents, and just store that in Redis (as opposed to just storing the path of the file). Using the following:

```
$contents = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
UploadFileToCloud::dispatch($filePath, $contents, $lead)->onQueue('s3-uploads');
```

I have quite a large Redis store, so I am confident I can do this for lots of small files (most likely in my case), but some files can be quite large.

I am starting to have concerns that I may run into issues using this method, most likely issues to do with my Redis store running out of memory.

I have thought about a shared drive between all my instances and revert back to my original method of storing the file path, but unsure.

Another issue I have is if a file upload fails, if it's a big file, can the `failed_jobs` table handle the amount of data (for example) of a base64 encoded 20mb pdf.

Is base64 encoding the file contents and queuing that the best method? Or, can anyone recommend an alternative means to queue uploading a file upload in a multi server environment?

Comment: What about using Presigned URLs (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) to have just have the server authorize the action, but then have the user actually perform the upload directly to s3.

Comment: You may find that uploading the file to S3 is a sufficiently fast operation that this abstraction/optimization is unnecessary.   If the bucket is in your EC2 region, and particularly if you use an S3 endpoint, you have bandwidth to S3 limited only by the bandwidth of the instance, itself.

Comment: Thanks for the replies Jamie/MIchael, I understand that I could, but I am concerned about S3 failing (has happened, probably will happen again), so I would like the ability to "retry" any failed jobs/uploads.